# Extracting strings from different columns and tidying data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, string-matching, stringr, stringi

I am trying to extract a strings of the movie type from a data set. The data is in the following format where the genre types are randomly distributed in the dataset by different reviewers.Luckily there are only 4 genre types (comedy, action, horror, scifi) in the dataset, but there are also repetitions. So I need to extract those strings from the dataset.

```
id  movie v1      v2           v3       v4         v5     v6  
1   LTR   comedy  highbudget   action   comedy     jj     horror
2   MI    newmovie  fiction     scifi    funny      xx    jhee
```

I am expecting an output of the following form.

```
id  movie   genretype1 genretype2 genretype3   genretype4
1   LTR     comedy     action     comedy       horror
2   MI      scifi      ---        ---          ---
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I need to create new columns called genretype1, genretype2 etc and it should get the values from the columns (v1: v6).

Comment: @akrun this is just a dummy data. Grouping into one column doesn't have a meaning and it corresponds to the first genre type.

Comment: It's okay.  Anyway, you got a solution.  I hope I will a chance to help you in the future

Comment: Cheers @akrun I think that solution won't work as i need to concatenate strings further for analysis. Let me know if you have a pseud solution!

Comment: Perhaps `lst1 <- apply(df1[-(1:2)], 1, function(x) types[match(x, types, nomatch=0)]); data.frame(df1[1:2], do.call(rbind,lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1)))))` where types is from SenorO's post

Comment: Great the first line of code worked really well. I have trouble in binding the columns. I am getting the error "Error: unexpected symbol in "data.frame(dataset[1:2] do.call"

Comment: Ok, it is the backquotes, that caused the trouble. `do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, 'length<-', max(lengths(lst1))))`

Comment: I have no words to express my happiness! Thanks a lot @akrun

Comment: Hi @akrun! I hope you are doing great. Can you answer this question which i posted in a different thread? [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478685/text-mining-pdf-files-issues-with-word-frequencies). I made it reproducible. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `match`  the 'types' with each row of 'df1' excluding the 1st two identifier columns.  The length of `list` elements in the 'lst1' may not be the same.  We make the length equal by padding `NA` values to elements that have shorter length than the maximum length element, `rbind` the list elements and create a new `data.frame`.

```
 types <- c("comedy", "action", "horror", "scifi")
 lst1 <- apply(df1[-(1:2)], 1, function(x) 
                       types[match(x, types, nomatch=0)])
 res <- data.frame(df1[1:2], do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, 
                             'length<-', max(lengths(lst1)))))
 res
 # id movie     X1     X2     X3     X4
 #1  1   LTR comedy action comedy horror
 #2  2    MI  scifi   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

NOTE: We can change the column names if it is needed.

```
colnames(res)[-(1:2)] <- paste0('genretype', 1:4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it - it makes more sense to use a list, not a data.frame

```
> types = c("comedy", "action", "horror", "scifi")
> List = apply(df, 1, function(x) types[types %in% x[-c(1, 2)]])
> names(List) <- df$movie
> List
$LTR
[1] "comedy" "action" "horror"

$MI
[1] "scifi"
```

Alternatively, this solution could give you a tidy data.frame:

```
> Matrix = t(apply(df, 1, function(x) types %in% x[-c(1, 2)]))
> colnames(Matrix) = types
> cbind(df[,1:2], Matrix)
  id movie comedy action horror scifi
1  1   LTR   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE FALSE
2  2    MI  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I need to have values listed like genretype1 genretype2 as i need to concatenate them for analysis.

Comment: Also when i list for LTR i am expecting comedy action comedy horror and not comedy action horror.